# Socket.io giving {} instead of the file, webhooks, Node.js

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to make a website where we upload a file, and it sends it to discord with webhooks. But the issue is that when i'm making the request from the client side to the server side, the file (formData variable) get transformed to {} and I don't want it to be transformed.

In the client side, the console.log(formData) gives me this:

[image]

But in the server side, the console.log(formData) gives me this:
[image]

Here's the code:

script.js:

```
let url = window.location.href;
let arr = url.split("/");
let result = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];

async function sendMessage() {
    socket = io(result);

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    formData.append("content", "File Submited");

    console.log(formData)
    socket.emit('send-webhook', formData);        
}
```

server.js

```
const axios = require('axios')

io.on('connection', async socket => {
  socket.on('send-webhook', async formData => {
    console.log(formData)
    await axios
      .post('WEBHOOK_LINK', {
        formData
      })  
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is that you cannot send `FormData` over WebSocket in that way.

The idea of `FormData` is to assemble and output that will be the same when sending the `multipart/form-data` Content-Type. And hence `FormData` is not intended to be used with WebSockets.

The easiest way here will be just to use a simple HTTP endpoint for file upload. As a workaround, you could Base64 encode the file content and send it over WebSocket, but this is a bad idea.

WebSockets were created for messaging between server and client, not for static files handling.